# DI Unity in multiple projects - best practises

Tags: wpf, wcf, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a question. I have WPF project with Unity DI container, library project and WCF project in common solution. In WCF library is service which read from the database. UserManager set in the constructor, but this has an error.

My question is must unity container be in each project in solution or I can configure one unity container so that it finds dependencies in the whole solution?

My container is configured as follows:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(), 
    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface, 
    WithName.Default);
```

But it doesn't resolve dependencies in the WCF application.

Comment: You only need a single container.

Comment: Thanks. Only one container for whole solution? My container is configured as follows: 

    var container = _container ?? (_container = new UnityContainer());
                container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(), WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface, WithName.Default);

 But dont inject dependency to WCF application.

Comment: If the WCF project sits on a remote server and the WPF application is on the client then each side will need one container.

Comment: Thanks, it's actually a logical. But how to configure WCF application for unity? in WPF create UnityContainer instance in App.xaml.cs, where configure container in WCF?

Comment: This MSDN article shows how to use Unity in WCF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323725(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> must unity container be in each project in solution or I can configure one unity container so that it finds dependencies in the whole solution?

Neither. You will typically have each start-up project create its own container, and configure its dependencies. Since you have multiple start-up projects (both a web service and a desktop application), you will have multiple places where you configure the container. This is related to the concept of the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). Also look at [Composition Root reuse](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/06/composition-root-reuse/) for more details.